# Change arrow style for default expansion panel arrow

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have an angular expansion panel as shown below.

[image]

But I want to change the the design of the arrow to something like this:

Not expanded:

[image]

Expanded:

[image]

How? or is it possible for me to do so in angular material?
Code below:

HTML:

```
<md-expansion-panel>
  <md-expansion-panel-header>
    <md-panel-title>
      Personal data
    </md-panel-title>
    <md-panel-description>
      Type your name and age
    </md-panel-description>
  </md-expansion-panel-header>

  <md-form-field>
    <input mdInput placeholder="First name">
  </md-form-field>

  <md-form-field>
    <input mdInput placeholder="Age">
  </md-form-field>
</md-expansion-panel>
```

TS:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Basic expansion panel
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'expansion-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'expansion-overview-example.html',
})
export class ExpansionOverviewExample {}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Give your expansion panel a reference id e.g. `example` and set the `hideToggle` property as `true`.

In the `<md-panel-description>`, you can place your icons and use the `expanded` property of the panel to show or hide the relevant icons.

```
  <md-expansion-panel  class="custom-header" hideToggle="true" #example>
    <md-expansion-panel-header>
      <md-panel-title>
        Personal data
      </md-panel-title>
      <md-panel-description>
        Type your name and age
        <md-icon *ngIf="!example.expanded">play_arrow</md-icon>
        <md-icon *ngIf="example.expanded">arrow_drop_down</md-icon>
      </md-panel-description>
    </md-expansion-panel-header>

    <md-form-field>
      <input mdInput placeholder="First name">
    </md-form-field>

    <md-form-field>
      <input mdInput placeholder="Age">
    </md-form-field>
  </md-expansion-panel>
```

To provide space between the icon and panel description, add the following classes in your component.css:

```
.custom-header .mat-expansion-panel-header-title, 
.custom-header .mat-expansion-panel-header-description {
  flex-basis: 0;
}

.custom-header .mat-expansion-panel-header-description {
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

I have used material icons. You can place your custom icons if you want. Here is a link to [**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-beta-kznp17?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: You corrected the source code from
https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/examples
because class="custom-header" is on mat-accordion who doesn't work

Comment: Thanks alot buddy.

Comment: @Faisal is there a way to generate `id` dynamically for multiple expansion panels?

Comment: @Zuber , what is the use case ?

Comment: i have multiple expansion panels say 5-6, as per your answer, giving and `id` to panel and conditionally check that `id` by using `ng-if` will solve the problem. but i need a dynamic solution to generate `id`. is there any solution you have? any help is appreciated :)

Comment: @Zuber, if you are generating them using loop, then the same key would work for every panel in the template.

Comment: for angular material I had to use

mat instead of md. And I used another._expanded instead of another.expanded for example 2 in the stackblitz demo

Answer (score 5):

extended the answer from @Faisal and as per the latest version of angular material, we will use `mat` prefix instead of `md` for the Material components.

> Angular Material 8.1.4

```
<mat-expansion-panel class="mb-15px" hideToggle="true" #xyz>
<mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <mat-panel-title class="font-weight-bold font-small">
    Info
  </mat-panel-title>
  <mat-panel-description>
    <mat-icon *ngIf="!xyz.expanded">play_arrow</mat-icon>
    <mat-icon *ngIf="xyz.expanded">arrow_drop_down</mat-icon>
  </mat-panel-description>
</mat-expansion-panel-header>
<mat-expansion-panel class="mb-15px" hideToggle="true" #xyz>
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2ybqai?file=app%2Fexpansion-overview-example.ts)

Comment: @ErayT try to give different `Id` to different panela. here i have used `#xyz`. you have to give unique `id` for e.g. `#xyz` , `#abc` and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Another pretty solution .. just add a span with fxFlex

```
  <mat-panel-description>
       <span fxFlex></span>
       <img src="">
   </mat-panel-description>
```

Don't forget to add **hideToggle** to the mat-expansion-panel

```
<mat-expansion-panel hideToggle>
```